# Replace column value based on subquery

Tags: mysql, join

Basically, I have a table, call it `regular`, that gives me the `service_id` for a given day of the week, and then another table, call it `exception`, that specifies certain dates when the `service_id` is different from what it usually is. Treat the `service_id` as opaque strings.

`regular`’s structure:

```
+-------------+------------+
| day_of_week | service_id |
+-------------+------------+
| sunday      | some_serv  |
| monday      | another    |
| tuesday     | another    |
```

(It goes on for the rest of the week, days can often have the same `service_id`)

`exception`’s structure:

```
+-------------+------------+
| date        | service_id |
+-------------+------------+
| 2013-05-11  | different  |
```

(It has several dates like this)

Basically, what I want is a query that will return today’s `service_id`, which is the value for the day of the week *unless* there is an exception in the second table, in which case it should be that `service_id`.

I don’t see any good way to `JOIN` because the `service_id` columns are necessarily going to be different, and even with a `JOIN` I don’t know how to have the second table’s value replace the first table’s, which I need because I want this to be joined into a larger query so I can get just the results for today’s `service_id` (though I suppose I could do something like

```
WHERE (
    `exception`.`service_id`=Main.`service_id`
    OR
    (`exception`.`service_id` IS NULL AND `regular`.`service_id`=Main.`service_id`)
)
```

but that seems wasteful).

Changing the format of these tables is problematic for a variety of reasons.

Comment: paste the query please.

Comment: @ssedano I do not *have* a query. I have no idea how to write a query that will do what I want it to.

Comment: you can always do two left joins, one on the "weekdays" table, one on the "exceptions" table, and then use `IFNULL(exception.service_id, weekdays.service_id)` in the select clause

Comment: @Andreas Ah yes, `IFNULL` answers half of my question. But how do I do a `join` if there aren't any common values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do the following

```
SELECT XXX,
       IFNULL(exception.service_id, weekdays.service_id)
FROM  maintable
 LEFT JOIN weekdays ON DAYOFWEEK(maintable.date) = weekdays.day_of_week 
 LEFT JOIN exceptions on maintable.date = exceptions.date
```

Of course, you would need to convert the integer return value of `DAYOFWEEK` to the string equivalent expected by the weekdays table.

You could do that by using a `CASE` statement in the `JOIN` condition:

```
SELECT XXX,
       IFNULL(exception.service_id, weekdays.service_id)
FROM  maintable
 LEFT JOIN weekdays ON weekdays.day_of_week 
                        = CASE WHEN DAYOFWEEK(maintable.date) = 1 THEN 'sunday'
                               WHEN DAYOFWEEK(maintable.date) = 2 THEN 'monday'
                               ..
                          END
 LEFT JOIN exceptions on maintable.date = exceptions.date
```

To only get the service_id, you could just fire two separate queries; if you absolutely want just one query, you can do the following:

```
SELECT IFNULL((SELECT service_id 
               FROM exceptions
               WHERE exceptions.date = $somevalue
              ),
              (SELECT service_id 
               FROM weekdays
               WHERE weekdays.day_of_week 
                        = CASE WHEN DAYOFWEEK($somevalue) = 1 THEN 'sunday'
                               WHEN DAYOFWEEK($somevalue) = 2 THEN 'monday'
                               ..
              )
             ) AS service_id
```

Comment: This does look promising, but `maintable` doesn't have a `date` column, just the `service_id` column that I want to get. I was supplying the date by just using PHP to insert today's date (and the day's name) into the query. Can I just use that in the `ON`? I've never tried that but it seems like it might work...

Comment: If the date is not part of the maintable, you should precompute this value in a second query which you execute separately.  That would be much more efficient.

Comment: Could you give an example of that, please? Thanks.

Comment: OK, I've got something similar to this working. The trick I used was to use a sub-query for my FROM to add the date to the maintable. Is there a problem with doing that, performance-wise?

Comment: see edit.  Regarding your second question: the subquery result will be the same for each row, so It would be more efficient to compute it just once, rather than compute it for each an every row

Comment: Well, I actually added it to the result of the regular table, not maintable, which is only ever going to return one row anyhow. However, I like your edit better, much clearer what it's doing.